# Error logs Kettle/Data Integration(Pentaho) and execution information of the transformations

Tags: kettle

I need to do an analysis of the kettle errors (Data Integration).

How do I get information when just running a job in the kettle (Data Integration) and the result of this execution?

Comment: Do you want to know when a job ends? or you want to know the logging technique in pdi ?? ... not clear with the question exactly.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not very clear. I need two pieces of information. I want to know when the job ended and where the kettle stores the log of the execution of jobs. The ultimate goal is to create an efficient monitoring tool.